# PDF is always created with A4 paper size

Tags: paper-size

I use MikTex 2.9 and TeXstudio 2.6.2 on a Win 7 64-bit machine. I create my LaTeX documents with the following build settings:
[image]

MiKTeX is set to `letterpaper` as default paper size:
[image]

In my LaTeX document I specify paper size `letterpaper` in the document preamble, as shown in the sample code below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
Test document.
\end{document}
```

However, my `.pdf`-file is always typeset on 'A4 paper' and not 'letterpaper'. Is there another paper size setting I should use?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be letter, I think. But the best solution is to add `\usepackage{geometry}`.

Comment: @cfr: No, `letterpaper` is the right name of the relevant option.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I know. I didn't mean 'It should be `letter`' but only that it should be letter. That is, I'd expect it to output letter given those settings.

Comment: @cfr: Oops, sorry!  A funny misunderstanding, isn’t it? :-)

Comment: Try compiling the following code: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\the\pdfpageheight\end{document}`.  What output do you get?

Comment: ;) A scope ambiguity + mark-up confusion = misunderstanding ??

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti ^^

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Your solution will of course work, but the question is, why aren’t the physical page dimensions set to the dimension for the letter format in the OP’s `pdftexconfig.tex` file (given the fact the the OP has set this paper format in the MikTeX configuration window)?  I cannot answer, because I’ve never used MikTeX.

Comment: how do you determine the PDF is on A4?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Are you sure it shouldn't be `\pdfpageheight=\paperheight` and `\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth`?

Comment: @naphaneal The difference between letter size and A4 is visually obvious, but to tell that it is really US letter and not just very close, for example, or really A4 and not just very close, you can view the PDF properties in your viewer or use `pdfinfo <filename>`.

Comment: @cfr yes, I'm aware of properties. I meant, how the OP knows the PDF is in A4 and not USLetter. simply put: how does he figure it out?

Comment: @naphaneal Do you mean, is the OP looking at the properties? How else would you check?

Comment: @cfr comparing the PDF to a printout and look for differences. i call it: the 'look & feel'-approach. Look on it and see if it feels right. :D

Comment: @naphaneal Or if it feels wrong. As I said, the difference between US letter and A4 is palpable. Depending on where I'm living one feels wrong and the other feels right. If I switch countries, this flips after a little bit.